# Regular Expression help skip lines "/*X" but not "/**/

Tags: regex, pcre

So for PCRE (PHP) regular expressions, I'm trying to read output from a search on the mainframe platform from the development team.

I need to parse out file names so I can join back into other lists I am tracking details of a system migration.

My expression so far is on Regex101.com [here](https://regex101.com/r/azpI3B/2) with sample data.
I'm certain there are more efficiencies I can introduce, but for now I'm looking to meet the requirement before I go down that road.

Here is the code for reference

```
^(?#
Objective is to capture the first two columns: program name and line number.  This part is easy

I'm able to skip lines with comments and start parsing at the 'QRY' string.

Challenge is I would like to skip lines like this
.*\/\*QRY.*$
and include lines like this [end comment appears before the 'QRY' string]
.*\/\*.*\*\/QRY.*$

Check for comment indicator and skip lines with comments
)(?!.*\/\*.*(?!\*\/)QRY)(?#
)(?#
Program name
)^(?<prgName>.+?)[[:blank:]](?#
QRY clause
)(?:.*QRY\((?<qryName>.*?)\))*(?#
FILE or QRYFILE clause
)(?:.*FILE\(\((?<qryFile01>.*?)\)(?:[[:blank:]]\((?<qryFile02>.*?)\)\))*)*
```

Comment: "Mainframe" is a word that I've not heard for many moons.

Answer (score 0):

Try `'~(?mi)(?:(?:^.*?/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*QRY.*$(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|^(?<prgName>.+?)[[:blank:]](?:.*QRY\((?<qryName>.*?)\))*(?:.*FILE\(\((?<qryFile01>.*?)\)(?:[[:blank:]]\((?<qryFile02>.*?)\)\))*)*)~'`

features

- line oriented *only*, does not validate comments
- SKIP's line if QRY after start of comment begin
- passes line where QRY is outside comment

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/OnQsup/1)